# Tensorflow LSTM training by batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have coded a LSTM RNN with x being of shape [n_batch=25, seq_len=250, n_inputs=1]. I trained the model on pieces of the sin function, and predict another piece. Here is the result. I reshaped the predictions from [n_batch=25, seq_len=250, n_output=1] to [test_len=2000, n_ouput=1][[image: LSTM prediction on sin function]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwWXk.png)

You see that it drops to 0 at the beginning of every batch. My code is the following:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init_op)
            training_mse = []
            zero_state = sess.run(initial_state)

            for epoch in range(100):
                current_state = zero_state
                feed_dict = {
                        tf_x: train_x, 
                        tf_y: train_y, 
                        initial_state : current_state, 
                }

                sess.run(self.optimize, feed_dict = feed_dict)

                cost, current_state = sess.run([error, final_state], feed_dict = feed_dict)

def forward(self):
        tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, seq_len, n_inputs])
        tf_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, seq_len, n_outputs])

        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

        layers = [
                tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(10)
            for _ in range(n_layers)
        ]

        cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(layers)

        initial_state = cells.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

        outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                cells,
                tf_x,
                initial_state = initial_state,
                dtype = tf.float32
        )

        outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, self.params.n_neurons])
        predictions = tf.matmul(outputs, W2) + b2
```

I think it is due to the initial_state of the lstm cells but not sure why it does this. Any idea?

Comment: According to your code, you feed the full data set. How do you do batching?

Comment: Yep you're right. Forgot to add the get next batch code. But even when feeding the full sample it should not drop to 0. I give x0 to x250, then another x0 to x250. And it looks like for every x0 the model predicts 0...

Comment: what is the difference between training the model on a matrix of (batch, seq_length) and a vector of (batch * seq_length) ?